# Can I change the default layout ruler guides in FlexBuilder 3?

Tags: apache-flex, layout, flex3, canvas, flexbuilder

I'm using FlexBuilder 3.  I love the way the layout guides tell you when a component you're placing on a canvas is so far from the next component (presumably 8 pixels).  Is it possible to change the distance at which the ruler guide pops up?  I'm putting a series of labels close together and would like to change this to, say, 4 pixels.

I can line the components up manually, but this is time consuming and is subject to human error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know that is not possible. You can only enable/disable snapping to the rulers but there is no option to specify the spacing.